# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Setup Failure on SQL Native Client

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I attempted to install Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013, but I get the error shown in the image

[image]

When I drill donw into the error log I noticed the following message:

> Installation of Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime failed. Exit code: 5100.
> Result: Asia

As a result I decided to abort the installation CRM 2013 and tried to install Microsoft Dynamics CRM Setup. Everything appears to be going in the right direction, however I keep on getting the error that the Download failed for SQL Native Client, see image.

[image]

I have turned off the Firewall to make sure that the Firewall was blocking the download.

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong?
I am tring to install on Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2014

Answer (score -3):

To resolve this problem I manually downloaded the SQL 2008 native client from [Microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57606).

Make sure to restart the Server post installation.